# Android App Invites does not show in notification Facebook android however linvitation is listed in facebook/apps/app invites

Tags: android, fbsdkappinvitecontent

I'm using App Invites feature from android Facebook SDK.
I have a issue that is when I sent invitation to my friend but this invitation didn't show in notification friend's Facebook Android Application however invitation is listed in facebook/apps/app invites
[App/App Invites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRg8I.png)

Has anyone encountered this problem yet? 
Can u give a application that have App Invites feature and has been worked? I need test to make sure if problem from Facebook.

Thank ad